# SwiftUI appear transition doesn't work inside NavigationStack

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation, swiftui-navigationstack, swiftui-transition

When I tap on an item in a list, I'd like to transition a view in from the leading edge.

Currently:

- When I use `ListView` by itself, the *appear* transition works fine.
- When I wrap `ListView` in a `NavigationStack`, the `Image`'s *appear* transition **does not occur**. The `Text` transitions correctly.
- In both instances, the *disappear* transition works fine.

Below is a minimal example (including preview providers) to demonstrate what I'm talking about:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ListView: View {
    @State var selected: Int? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        List(0..<4) { index in
            HStack {
                if selected == index {
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                        .transition(.move(edge: .leading).combined(with: .opacity))
                }
                Text("\(index)")
                Spacer()
            }
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture { selected = index }
            .animation(.default, value: selected == index)
        }
    }
}

struct AnimationBroken_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ListView()
        }
    }
}

struct AnimationWorks_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ListView()
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems to work for me when I use: `if selected == index {
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                        .transition(.move(edge: .leading).combined(with: .opacity))
                    Text("\(index)") } else { Text("\(index)") }`